# Jasmine Spy - expectToHaveBeenCalled() failing

Tags: angular, jasmine, spy

I'm dealing with a very simple spec -

```
fit('should create', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'setTotals')();
    expect(component.setTotals).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
});
```

by which my understanding is - spying on this method, and expecting that it has been called - will create a success.

However, the opposite is occurring, and I do not quite see why. It seems to me I am using spies in the correct manner. Any input on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
spyOn(component, 'setTotals');
```

Or:

```
spyOn(component, 'setTotals').and.callThrough();
```